# Wireless greyed out with an Intel 3945ABG

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP laptop and cannot enable my wireless card.  I have checked the BIOS and it is enabled there. I have checked the drivers and I think I have the correct one.  The option to enable wireless is grayed out. I am a new Ubuntu user so any help would be appreciated.

My laptop has an Intel/PRO 3945 wireless card installed.

Here is a printout of `lspci -vv`:

```
10:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 135b
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 46
    Region 0: Memory at e4100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
    Kernel modules: iwl3945
```

Please let me know if any other information would help.

Comment: does it show in the grayed wireless line that it is "disabled by hardware switch" or something like that? - in which case type in terminal `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`. Just type it anyway to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to your router or modem with an ethernet cable and then check the Additional Drivers program (open up Launcher and search for "driver" and it should come up). I have a laptop with an Intel wireless card and I had to install the driver from Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, have you checked the physical Wifi on/off switch on the laptop?